# fs.readFile looks in wrong folder after electron-packager

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm working on the demo [electron-quick-start](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start) project. I just added, in the main folder, a `test.txt` file and this in `index.html` :

```
<script>
const fs = require('fs');
alert(fs.readFileSync('test.txt'));        // or ./test.txt or .\test.txt
</script>
```

It works.
But now after having packaged the app with :

```
electron-packager . --platform=win32 --arch=ia32
```

when I run the packaged .exe app, it doesn't find the test.txt.
Probably because the `test.txt` **is not** in the same folder than the .exe but rather in `resouces/app/test.txt`.

**What's the clean way to solve this electron-packager folder issue?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved it by using `__dirname` :

```
const path = require('path');
var datafile = path.join(__dirname, 'test.txt');
```